How to make the Dock appear permanently on Pantheon Desktop environment on Ubuntu 22.04
I just installed the Pantheon Desktop environment on Ubuntu 22.04.
I used those commands (that I found there: https://techviewleo.com/install-pantheon-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu/):
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install elementary-icon-theme elementary-default-settings elementary-desktop


Is it possible to make the Taskbar/Dock (list of icons on the top bar of the desktop) appear permanently instead of having to place the mouse cursor over it and wait for the dock to appear?


@Ajay thanks for your comment. I edited the question accordingly. Do you have an idea?

Seems something you should ask the people that made DE.

@David Thank you for your comment. Do you know who / which github exactly by any means?

The dock in Pantheon DE is an app called Plank. You can customize, modify, or even delete it from Apps -> Tweaks -> Cerebere -> Plank


thanks for your answer, unfortunately I don't find Tweak nor Cerebre in my applications

I also added the command I used to install the desktop environment and I wonder if it is the correct one

May I ask you where you found the information?
